# Asp.Net CultureInfo switching: trying to avoid non postback calls

Tags: asp.net

As if in this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18753/Developing-an-ASP-NET-page-with-MasterPage-and-Loc) I implemented an easy way to switch between languages on a website.

The issue is if I want to switch languages with a dropdown list, and leave the last selected language on the dropdown list control's view.

Every article I've seen about CulturalInfo-switching sends a `Server.transfer()` call right after the language switch, and that event causes the non-postback page reloading, including my dropdownlist control which realoads from default position.

I tried a `response.redirect()`, but it still is a non postback call

I think I need a way to check if it's a `Server.transfer()` call in the page load, but still haven't found a way to develop this

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you followed the same approach as in that article, how about this:

```
string path = this.Request.Path;

if (path.LastIndexOf('?') > 0)
    path += "&lang=" + senderLink.CommandArgument;
else
    path += "?lang=" + senderLink.CommandArgument;

this.Server.Transfer(path);
```

Then, on the page that `this.Server.Transfer` executes, get `lang` value from `this.Request.QueryString["lang"]`, and set the dropdown's `SelectedItem` appropriately.

Alternatively, keep `Server.Transfer(Request.Path);`, but on the receiving page, parse `Session["MyCulture"]` instead to set the dropdown. +1